# Issues with sending lines over netcat to Python

Tags: python, sockets

I am piping a program's stdout to netcat: `nc -u localhost 50000`.  Listening on UDP 50000 is a Python program that does something like this:

```
  lstsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  lstsock.setblocking(0)

  while True:
        print '1'
        try:
            tmp = lstsock.recv(SOCK_BUFSZ)
        except socket.error, e:
            if e.args[0] == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                sleep(.5)
                continue
            else:
                print("Socket error: {}".format(e))
                return
        print tmp
```

I'll always get a few lines, but then the program hangs on `print '1'`.  When I run the line-generating program, the output is a line to stdin about every second.  What's going on here?

Edit, in case it's somehow related: The program producing lines is in docker (run with `--net="host"`, and the server (accepting lines) is on the host running docker.  Docker is sending it over 127.0.0.1.

Another edit: It seems to stop accepting input when SOCK_BUFSZ bytes were received.  It's not recycling the buffer?

Update: this seems to be an issue with Docker.  It works on localhost, but not from the container.  I have connectivity (I can ping the server, and the first burst of data gets through).

Comment: May I ask you to show us your netcat script?

Comment: @DavidCullen - ./command | nc -u localhost 50000

Answer (score 1):

This Python script worked for me:

```
import socket

lstsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
lstsock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 50000))

SOCK_BUFSZ = 4096
counter = 1
while True:
    print "counter = %s" % counter
    counter += 1
    data, addr = lstsock.recvfrom(SOCK_BUFSZ)
    print data
```

I used this bash script to send lines:

```
while true ;
do
    echo "Running..."
    echo -n "hello" | nc -w 0 -u "127.0.0.1" 50000
    sleep 1
done
```

I didn't see the point of setting the socket to be non-blocking when time was wasted in a sleep.

After [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629064/issues-with-sending-lines-over-netcat-to-python/39629948#comment66565411_39629948) from [horse_hair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246078/horse-hair), I put put the server in a thread:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

SOCK_BUFSZ = 4096

def udp_server(quit_flag):
    udp_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    udp_sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 50000))
    counter = 1
    while not quit_flag.is_set():
        print "counter = %s" % counter
        counter += 1
        data, addr = udp_sock.recvfrom(SOCK_BUFSZ)
        print data

def main():
    quit_flag = threading.Event()
    udp_thread = threading.Thread(target=udp_server, args=(quit_flag,))
    udp_thread.daemon = True
    udp_thread.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1.0)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Exiting due to keyboard interrupt"
    quit_flag.set()
    udp_thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Everything still works.

Comment: I get the first 'hello' then nothing for a long time, then a 'hello' again, repeat.  Also, I get 'invalid wait time' when using the -w 0 option with netcat.  The only difference is that my netcat is apparently different than yours, and I'm running through docker.  Oh, and my receive loop is in a thread.  Simply looping and printing 'hello' in the thread (without receiving from the network) works, so doesn't seem like there's delay in the run loop.

Comment: What version of `netcat` are you using? The `nc` on both OS X and Linux allows me to use `-w 0`. What is the output of `ls -hl $(which nc)`?